# QGIS - rules. Finding roads crossing cities with query

Tags: rules, qgis

On same layer in QGIS I have highways (primary, secondary etc.) and cities boundaries (place=city). I want to show/label only primary roads crossing cities. I try something like
`"highway"  =  'tertiary' AND "place" = 'city'`
but got no items, when
`"highway"  =  'tertiary'`
alone returns 6 elements.
Or maybe another way? How can I find crossing elements?

Answer (score 0):

Since both your target variables are in the same layer it seems to be a query problem.

Have you checked if the condition that you are looking for really exists in your dataset?

If so, like many things in QGIS, Rule-based Labeling uses **S**tructured **Q**uery **L**anguage (SQL), which is strongly typed, to fetch the data you are looking for. Thereby, it's important to be sure about the data types of your dataset and be aware of the double-quote pattern for "column" and single quote for the 'values', if they are varchar or string, exactly as you already did in your example.

Furthermore, check if the values that you are trying to match, in your Rule-based Labeling, are written exactly as they appear in your data attribute table. Anyway, if your dataset is huge, you can use this approach as a workaround:

```
"highway" ilike '%tertiary% and "place" ilike '%city%'
```

The `ilike` operator will make no difference from the upper or lower case in your query, which means that if you have a value 'Tertiary' it would be possible to fetch the data anyway.
Besides, as I put it, the wildcard character `%` finds any values that have the strings 'tertiary' and 'city' in any position, which can avoid lots of headaches due to whitespaces before or after the string.